# Finding last trade from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table of trades, which have the form (for simplicity):

```
    Ticker    Timestamp    price
0    AAPL       9:30:00   139
1    FB         11:33:14   110
```

And so on. Now, I want to extract the last trade for the day for each ticker, which is certainly possible thus (assuming the original table is called `trades`).

```
trades['Timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(trades['Timestamp'])
aux = trades.groupby(['Ticker'])['Timestamp'].max()
auxdf = aux.to_frame()
auxdf = auxdf.reset_index()
closing = pd.merge(left=trades,right=auxdf, left_on=['Ticker','Timestamp'],right_on=['Ticker', 'Timestamp'])
```

Now, this works, but I am not sure if it is either the most elegant or the most efficient approach. Any suggestions?

Comment: trades.groupby(['Ticker']).last() will save you the rest of the steps

Comment: @A-Za-z Ah, you mean if the trades were already sorted (which, of course, they would be). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ix and idxmax:

```
trades['Timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(trades['Timestamp']
trades.ix[trades.groupby('Ticker').Timestamp.idxmax()]
```